# What is the difference between privapp-permissions.xml in system/etc/permissions and default-permissions.xml in system/etc/default-permissions?

Tags: android, permissions, android-permissions, android-source

What is the difference between privapp-permissions.xml in system/etc/permissions and default-permissions.xml in system/etc/default-permissions?

For refernce: https://github.com/opengapps/opengapps/issues/518#issuecomment-355230967

The link didn't understand properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Every private permissions used by apps in /system/priv-app/ should be put in privapp-permissions.xml.
2. The dangerous permissions used by apps in /system/ can be granted by default by system/etc/default-permissions.

private permissions are permissions declared in platfrom with system|signatured flags.
dangerous permissions are runtime permissions should be granted by users.

Comment: If I have a postloaded app located in data/app. Is there a way to modify a default-permissions.xml file so the approval of the dangerous permission is given by default?

Comment: I am thinking to sideload call recording app to system privileged apps, this app requires permissions to modem line, this way I can use the app without polluting my os with root access, will it work?

Comment: @Suhayb yes, it will works. And what's the permission to modem line?

Comment: @Yong, I meant to record the call using Line not mic which requires root